# Laggy Safari Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I know there are other posts same as this, but I wanted to ask maybe its my Jquery code that is the issue.

Chrome, Firefox even IE 10+ is working smooth with this approach. Safari is very laggy and I think it might be jquery. Because "top:" value is taking a little while to update. Not sure what could be causing this.

Here is Jquery:

```
 $(document).scroll(function() {

    var windowSize = $(window).width();

    if (windowSize > 1019) {

        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 380) {

            if ($('.sub-nav').closest('.standard-content').height() > ($(document).scrollTop() + $('.sub-nav').outerHeight()+70)){
                $('.sub-nav').css('top', $(document).scrollTop() - 400);
            }     
        }

        else {
            $('.sub-nav').css('top', 0);
        }
    }   
});
```

CSS:

```
.side-nav {
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .sub-nav {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            left: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            @include transition(top, .1s, linear);
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar match-height">
                    <aside>
                        <h3>Sub-menu title</h3>
                        <div class="side-nav">
                            <ul class="sub-nav">
                                <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu item</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sub-menu item</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sub-menu item</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sub-menu item</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </aside>
                </div>
```

Safari animation is really bad.. Not sure why. As I mentioned all other browsers seem to be fine. Maybe the reason behind the lag is my JQuery. CSS I've tried everything with -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); etc...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `transform` attribute, not the `top` attribute.

So make your javascript code:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {

    var windowSize = $(window).width();
    var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > 380) {

        if ($('.content').height() > ($('.sub-nav').outerHeight()+70)){
            $('.sub-nav').css('transform', 'translate3d(0, ' + (scroll - 400) + 'px, 0)');
        }     
    } else {
        $('.sub-nav').css('transform', 'translate3d(0,0,0)');
    }
});
```

Comment: I only have translate3d(0,0,0) in to force Hardware acceleration. It doesnt do anything else.

Comment: You should change the `transform` instead of the `top`. This is, because its visual result is the same, but performance is way better.

Comment: What I'm saying is: Just trust me. When it works, you can google "css why to use translate rather than position" to learn more.

Comment: Hi, did tis answer work for you? If you feel this answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: As a side note, accordingly to my experiments; whilst using `transform:translate()` instead of `top/left/right/bottom` for animation performance is better in general, if the amount of translation exceeds the viewport bounds then animation framerate drops and it barely animates all frames and jumps to end state before duration totally consumed. This can be caused by performance optimization that applied for out-of-view animations on mobile devices. So, don't use `transform: translate` for positioning elements before/outside animation if you gonna animate that element to keep smooth.